# differential amplifier ac equivalent circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, differential

In figure a, \$R_E\$ is clearly in series with the base emitter reisistance \$r_e'\$ of \$Q_2\$.
But in figure b, why are they putting \$r_e'\$ in parallel with \$R_E\$?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the small signal equivalent circuit in the figure below:
[image]

Since the base is also grounded the resistor \$r_e\$ becomes parallel to \$R_E\$. This circuit is just rearranged in the figure you show.

Comment: I notice that, but I still have an issue: In your figure the base ground is between \$Q2\$ current source and \$r_e'\$, but in my figure the base ground is after \$r_e'\$.

Comment: You are right, the base connection seems a bit dodgy to me as well. To me the equivalent circuit seems wrong. But if you just want to calculate the gain, you don't need these simplifications, I think just use the above small signal model and you can easily find its gain.

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one thinks it's incorrect! Thanks again:)

Comment: Where do you see any error? Base connection? Tell me, where in the equivalent diagrams you can see any base node for Q2? All the equivalent diagrams are OK - and the confusion comes from the fact that the inverse transconductance (1/gm) is - unfortunately - modeled using a resistive symbol. This is a vry bad method because - as we can see - it leads to confusion. Note that 1/gm is expressed in V/A=ohms - however, IT IS NOT A RESISTOR !!

Comment: @LvW In the original circuit, the base is connected to ground but in the small signal model it is connected to RE which has non-zero voltage. If you can explain it, please answer.

Comment: @sarthak...why did you not answer my question (where in the small signal model for Q2 is a base node)? The resistor RE is connected to the emitter of Q2 !